# Looking for some ideas on how to create a graph from a sql table and output it to a webpage

Tags: javascript, vbscript, graph

I am familiar with vbscript, I am looking for a few ideas on how to do this. I am open to trying other scripting languages. The graph does not have to be incredibly fancy. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it have to be interactive? (react to user input) or can it be just an image. Since you are interacting with a database I assume you don't have to use a client-side api for your graphs.

Comment: no it does not have to be interactive

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google Chart Api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It's really simple.

Store datapoints in a database and then render it as a url that you just put in the page.